# How can i handle 500 error thrown by jetty on apache

Tags: apache, jetty

I am using jetty as my app server and apache as webserver to proxy requests to jetty. In some cases jetty throws 500 internal server error with stack trace. I want to handle this 500 error on apache i.e. i want to configure apache to suppress this 500 error and show an html page.

I configured apache with
ErrorDocument 500 http://abc.com/errorpage.html

but still i am getting 500 error from jetty with HTTP ERROR 500 followed by stack trace and footer as 
"Powered by Jetty://"

How can i suppress this error at apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ProxyErrorOverride directive should work for you:

```
# Let mod_proxy serve error pages.
ProxyErrorOverride On

# This also allows for SSI, so you can trap the error code and act accordingly.
ErrorDocument 500 /static/500.shtml
```

Comment: Thanks. this works. I was expecting ProxyErrorOverride to be on by default.